# How to draw a parabol through three points C2',Q',C1'?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pstricks-add,pst-intersect}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-7,-2)(6,6)
\pnodes(-1,2){M}(4,-.5){N}(-1,-1){X}(0,5){Y}(2,-1){Q}
\psline(X)(Y)
\pssavepath{parabol}{\parabola(4,3)(Q)}
\pssavepath{lineMN}{\psline(M)(N)}
\psintersect[name=C,showpoints]{parabol}{lineMN}
\pstOrtSym{X}{Y}{C1,C2,Q}
\parabola(C1')(Q')
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A]

Comment: Are you also interested in drawing rotated parabola?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are looking for a mirrored parabola:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-intersect,pst-optic,pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-7,-2)(6,6)
    \pnodes(-1,2){M}(4,-.5){N}(-1,-1){X}(0,5){Y}(2,-1){Q}
    \psline(X)(Y)
    \pssavepath{parabol}{\parabola(4,3)(Q)}
    \pssavepath{lineMN}{\psline(M)(N)}
    \psintersect[name=C,showpoints]{parabol}{lineMN}
    \pstOrtSym{X}{Y}{C1,C2,Q}
    \parabola(C1')(Q')
  \psset{linewidth=1.5pt}   
  \parabola[linecolor=red](4,3)(Q)% same as (x-2)^2-1
  \symPlan(X)(Y){\psplot[linecolor=blue,algebraic]{0}{4}{(x-2)^2-1}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: " \symPlan(X)(Y){\parabola[linecolor=red](4,3)(Q)} ". Can we have the result if we don't have the equation of ...? :-)

Comment: Not with the node, but with the coordinates: `\symPlan(X)(Y){\parabola[linecolor=blue](4,3)(2,-1)}`